# Dynamic Database Driven CSS

Tags: css, database, dynamic

Here is my problem, I have a site I am building. I am including an admin page to manage everything on the fly, that i have no issue with as it is pretty straight forward php, mysql etc. I have it in my head that i can use a database to store css and  dynamically call it up as i add new setting for the different classes, id's etc. my table is this:
settings
id--class--div--setting

Where class is something like body, header, footer, etc. and div and setting are as follows:

```
.header {
$div:$setting;
}
```

in my script i am echoing the style tag and including this inside of the head tags.

my code for what it is worth is below:

```
$header_query = mysql_query("SELECT style, setting FROM styles WHERE class='header'");
$header_result = mysql_fetch_array($header_query);


echo "<style type='text/css'>";
echo ".header {";
   foreach($header_result as $hstyle => $hsetting){
   echo $hstyle.":".$hssetting.";";
   }

   echo "}";
   echo "</style>";
```

I figgured that would be enough to echo each setting for that particular class and I was right in part. Instead of echoing out the desired code my echo(depending on the mysql_fetch command i use) spits out something like this:

```
<style>
.header {
0:div;1:background;2:setting;3:url(x.jpg)
}
</style>
```

Any ideas, I'm stumped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`mysql_fetch_array`](https://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_array) fetches one row. So you may use something like

```
$header_query = mysql_query("SELECT style, setting FROM styles WHERE class='header'");

echo "<style type='text/css'>";
echo ".header {";

while($header_result_row = mysql_fetch_array($header_query,MYSQL_ASSOC))
    echo $header_result_row['style'].":".$header_result_row['setting'].";";

echo "}";
echo "</style>";
```

Almost all `mysql_fetch_*` are only affecting a single row, keep that in mind. See also the [`mysql_fetch_array` examples](https://www.php.net/mysql_fetch_array#refsect1-function.mysql-fetch-array-examples).

Comment: Thanks as well for the fast answer! That worked! :) i am new to this so i would never have thought to use a while statement. that shows you i have a lot to learn.

Comment: @user1258619: You're welcome. Just a note: if you want to save user driven content in your database, make sure it's [correctly escaped](http://de.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string) to prevent [SQL injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) or use [prepared statements](http://de.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: Definitely, i hvae already sanitized my inputs for everything I just need to go over all of the content. the worst thing that is going to be stored there are user comments and progress much like a forum. very sound advice as i may need some help on that down the line.

Answer (score 0):

That's correct, because the mysql_fetch_array returns an array (hence the name) that contains an indexed list of all results, where each row is an associative array.

Use

```
echo $hssetting['style'].":".$hssetting['setting'].";";
```

and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! other forums i have posted to have not answered yet. i posted that and this is what is shown in my viewsource `code`<style type='text/css'>.header {:;:;:;:;}</style>`code`

Comment: on a side note i can echo the main query on screen as it connects to the DB correctly